# JQuery fadeTo() function doesn't work correctly on both elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't understand why the `.quote-container` opacity is higher than `#new-quote` if they are in the same `fadeTo()` function brackets and duration is the same.

What I mean, that during `fadeTo()` animation, `.quote-container` and `#new-quote` opacity should be same, for example: opacity: 0.12 and opacity: 0.12, so they should stop and start at the same time. But now, it's like opacity: 0.12 and opacity: 0.20. `#new-quote` element opacity should be the same as the first element.

---

There is my codepen: See the Pen [BJLPEV](https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/BJLPEV/) by Lukas ([@Kestis500](https://codepen.io/Kestis500)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

---

Unfortunately, I can't upload a video showing what is going on but the css opacity on both elements are the same: 0.

This line of code should be broken somehow:

```
getQuote().done(setTimeout(function() {
  $("#new-quote").outerHeight($(".quote-container").outerHeight());
}, 1000), $(".quote-container, #new-quote").fadeTo(10000, 1));

$(".quote-container, #new-quote").fadeTo(10000, 1));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You start timeout before the `getQuote()` request is done

Comment: Yes, what's wrong?

Comment: Does setTimeout() change fadeTo() behavior somehow?

Comment: I just tested fadeTo() without setTimeout(). Same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But, your code should be: `getQuote().done(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#new-quote").outerHeight($(".quote-container").outerHeight());
  }, 1000)
}, function() {
  $(".quote-container, #new-quote").fadeTo(10000, 1);
});` using anonymous wrapper functions so these methods are called once request deferred/promise is done. But like said, it is hard to figure out what you are trying to do regarding none working posted code. EDIT: sorry, i didn't see you posted codepen

Comment: @A.Wolff This code doesn't seem to work. No error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on these lines

```
$("body,  .button").animate({
  "background-color": colors[randomNumber]
});

$(".quote-text, .quote-author, #new-quote").animate({
  color: colors[randomNumber]
});
```

You are applying animate separately on #new-quote that cause delay in rendering. Either remove animation on #new-quote or add dummy animation to .quote-container. Change the above to

```
$("body, .button").animate({
  "background-color": colors[randomNumber]
});
$('.quote-container').animate({
  "padding": "2.5rem"
});

$(".quote-text, .quote-author, #new-quote").animate({
  color: colors[randomNumber]
});

$('.quote-container').animate({
  "padding": "2.5rem"
});
```

Comment: Check my pen now. I did what you said but this didn't fix the problem. Maybe I'm doing something wrong :/

Comment: I checked your pen and both elements reach opacity of 1 at the same time. Open your developer tools and check it out.

Comment: Oh yea, sorry :) But where should I change background color and color of these buttons now?

Comment: You do not need to animate them. You can directly set the values of background color and color. Another way of doing is adding classes that would set your background-color and color

Comment: But I want to animate them so the color and background changes like a transition.

Comment: Well then, add dummy animation to .quote-container so that both match. Check my edited answer. Not a recommended way but gets what you want.

Comment: Why is it padding and it's value is 2.5rem?

Comment: I just used a property of .quote-container from the css and animated it. It could have been anything.

Comment: But why do you use them 2 times instead of one?

Comment: #new-quote has a class button. You are using animate once on #new-quote and once on .button class. So animation is being applied twice on #new-quote and thus applying animation twice on .quote-container as well :)